# Java Thread attributes update automatically?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, server, client

I am really lost right now.

I have this `Server`, which for every client connected creates a new `Thread`, so it looks something like this:

```
Server.java

...
( new ServerReceiver( toClient, this.connectedPlayersObject ) ).start();
...
```

( `toClient` is a `ObjectOutputStream` and `this.connectedPlayerObject` is an object which manipulates an ArrayList )

that is called when

```
...
Socket socket = this.serverSocket.accept();
this.connectedPlayersObject.add( thisPlayer );
...
```

Anyway, everything ok in my Server.java, but in that thread i showed above, i have this:

```
ServerSender.java ( Thread )

...
private ConnectedPlayers CPO;
private ArrayList<Players> CPL;

public ServerSender( ObjectOutputStream _toClient, ConnectedPlayers _CPO ) {
    super( "ServerSender" );
    this.CPL = _CPO.get(); // returns the whole ArrayList that I have in this moment
    this.CPO = _CPO        // remember the object
}

public void run() {
    while( true ) {
        // here if the Server which starts the Thread is adding something to 
        // this.CPO's ArrayList, this.CPL gets that element inside of it too, why?
        this.printCPLs( this.CPL, this.CPO.get() ); // Prints both ArrayLists Nicely
    }
}
...
```

And they always print the same updated ArrayList, even if i never update `this.CPL`!

As you can see above, Server.java, every time a client connects, it adds the client to the `ArrayList` in `ConnectedPlayers` Object, so in the thread, i was expecting to get the right `ArrayList` when i call `.get();` but i get the right/updated elements on both the private attribute `this.CPL` and `this.CPO.get();`, so i can't figure when the `ArrayList` actually changed from a state to another

EDIT: The Object witch manipulates the ArrayList (CPO / connectedPlayersObject):

```
ConnectedPlayers.java    

public class ConnectedPlayers implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3225902114667506709L;

    private ArrayList<Player> connectedPlayers;

    public ConnectedPlayers() {
        this.connectedPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
    }

    public synchronized void add( Player _player ) { this.connectedPlayers.add( _player ); this.notifyChange(); }

    public ArrayList<Player> get() { return this.connectedPlayers; }

    private void notifyChange() {  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is very unclear.  _"And they always print the same thing, even if i never update this.CPL"_. If you never update it, it should stay the same.  What do you mean?  Also show more of your code, including the declarations of `CPL` and `CPO`.

Comment: Server.java adds clients as they connect inside an ArrayList from the Object `CPO`, which has some methods to manipulate that ArrayList ( like `.get();` to get the ArrayList or `.add();` to add the client to the ArrayList ). In the Thread, i get that object and i get the current ArrayList and set it as the attribute `CPL`, when the server adds something to that ArrayList through `CPO.add();` the attribute which had the initial ArrayList gets updated, even if i don't update it in the Thread. I don't know.. honesly how to make it clearer, i know it's somewhat messy...

Comment: @JimGarrison exactly, it should stay the same, but it does not, it updates when the ArrayList inside `this.CPO` updates

Answer (score 1):

All of your code keeps references to the same `ArrayList` object, because you never create copies of it. Therefore, when one part of the code adds an object to the `ArrayList`, it becomes visible to other places in the code which store references to the same `ArrayList`.

If you want to create a copy of the `ArrayList`, use `new ArrayList<Player>(originalList)`.

The fact that you're using threads is irrelevant here; threads in Java share the same memory space and have access to the same objects. Assigning an object to a thread attribute does not automatically create a copy of it.

Comment: `this.CPL = new ArrayList<Player>( this.CPO.get() )` didn't do the trick, i understood what you told me though.. i really don't know how to fix this, i just want to know when the Server actually changes the ArrayList ( either adding or removing elements ) and in my thread, the copy i do to that ArrayList still gets updated when i add elements to the ArrayList through the object..

Comment: I even manually created another ArrayList looping through the one i got from this.CPO.get(); and adding each element one by one.. still updates when server calls that object with .add();

Comment: Based on the code that you're showing, this cannot happen. Please try stepping through your code with a debugger. The debugger can show you the identity of every object, so you can see when you're working with the same object and when you have distinct copies.

Comment: YES! yeeees, this was it, you were right, it was just me referencing to the same ArrayList inside the object, thanks a million! Saved me from another week of staring at the same screen.